# SuperDoctor 5 won't install on CentOS 7.3.1611

Tags: supermicro

I'm having a problem installing SuperMicro's SuperDoctor 5 v5.4.0b703 onto a CentOS 7.3.1611 box with an X7DB3 motherboard.

I execute the binary (as root) and follow the prompts and eventually get dumped to the command prompt w/o anything being installed and just a directory and a log file for my trouble. Here's the log file:

```
   __________________________________________________________________________

Mon Jun 12 12:26:29 PDT 2017

Free Memory: 11593 kB
Total Memory: 35840 kB

2 Command Line Args:
0:  -m
1:  CONSOLE

java.class.path:
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/InstallerData
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/InstallerData/installer.zip

ZGUtil.CLASS_PATH:
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/InstallerData
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/InstallerData/installer.zip

sun.boot.class.path:
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/lib/resources.jar
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/lib/rt.jar
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/lib/jsse.jar
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/lib/jce.jar
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/lib/charsets.jar
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/lib/jfr.jar
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/classes

java.ext.dirs:
    /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre/lib/ext
    /usr/java/packages/lib/ext

java.version                  == 1.8.0_92 (Java 1)
java.vm.name                  == Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.vendor                == Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version               == 25.92-b14
java.vm.specification.name    == Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor  == Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version == 1.8
java.specification.name       == Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor     == Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version    == 1.8
java.vendor                   == Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url               == http://java.oracle.com/
java.class.version            == 52.0
java.library.path             == /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
java.compiler                 == null
java.home                     == /tmp/install.dir.9241/Linux/resource/jre
java.io.tmpdir                == /tmp
os.name                       == Linux
os.arch                       == amd64
os.version                    == 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64
path.separator                == :
file.separator                == /
file.encoding                 == UTF-8
user.name                     == root
user.home                     == /root
user.dir                      == /tmp/install.dir.9241
user.language                 == en
user.region                   == null
__________________________________________________________________________

Installed Feature(s) SuperDoctor5 of SD5

Install Begin: JUNE 12, 2017 12:25:27 AM PDT
Install End: JUNE 12, 2017 12:26:21 AM PDT

Installed by InstallAnywhere 17.0 Premier Build 5158


User Interactions
-----------------


#Choose an install folder
#------------------------
USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/Supermicro/SuperDoctor5

Summary
-------

Installation: Successful.

9 Successes
0 Warnings
0 NonFatalErrors
0 FatalErrors

Action Notes:

None

Install Log Detail:

Check Disk Space:         /opt/Supermicro/SuperDoctor5
                          Status: SUCCESSFUL
                          Additional Notes: NOTE - Required Disk Space:407,777,782 Bytes Free Disk Space:93,926,232,064 Bytes 

Execute Command:          grep /tmp /etc/mtab
                          Status: SUCCESSFUL

Execute Command:          grep /tmp /proc/mounts
                          Status: SUCCESSFUL

Execute Command:          getconf LONG_BIT
                          Status: SUCCESSFUL

Execute Script/Batch file:   Check the jvm version
                          Status: SUCCESSFUL

Execute Script/Batch file:   systemctl daemon-reload for rhel 7
                          Status: SUCCESSFUL

Execute Script/Batch file:   service sd5 status
                          Status: SUCCESSFUL


Execute Script/Batch file:   readlink -e /usr/bin/sdc.sh | sed 's/\/sdc.sh//g'
                          Status: SUCCESSFUL
```

No clue why it shows "SUCCESSFUL" for "service sd5 status" as there is no sd5 service and manually executing that command gets "Unit sd5.service could not be found."

It looks like its puking on extracting the sdc.sh script. I'm hoping someone's run into this and can point me in the right direction to get this figured out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SD5 will have created a directory in `/opt/Supermicro/SuperDoctor5` with file `startSD5Service.sh` to start the service.

Run manually as root to start the service or add to startup services.